# selenium and qt c++?

Tags: c++, qt, browser, selenium, browser-automation

Is it possible to use selenium with qt c++ ?

Seems like there are no official support from selenium for C++?

http://seleniumhq.org/download/

Comment: Am I right, that you want to test Qt applications with Selenium? Or you want just write tests in C++?

Comment: Rather than driving selenium via qt, you could drive QtWebKit. It would lack a bit of the infrastructure that selenium provides, but.. it's worked pretty good for me.

Answer (score 2):

There is a Webdriver for Qt applications: https://github.com/cisco-open-source/qtwebdriver

- Use a selenium bindings (python, java etc..) to write tests and send command with the wire protocol
- Install the Qtwebdriver on the Qt application side
- Then you can automate you Qt application with selenium tests

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to use json wire protocol to communicate with webdriver server within Qt/C++ application, but consider using some scripting language instead. For example Python is pretty easy to learn and has webdriver bindings.

http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/JsonWireProtocol

http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PythonBindings

Comment: Can you please tell me how to use json wire protocol thru a c++ application ,to automate a webbrowser?

Answer (score -1):

Please look library https://github.com/linotex/quelenium. I hope its help

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.